# Find the inverse of a $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

My matrix looks like this:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
    1&  1 & 1 & 1\\
    1& -1 & 1 & 0\\
    1&  1 & 0 & 0\\
    1&  0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\right)$$

The right lower half are all zeros.

Is there a quick way to find an inverse of this matrix?

I have the solution, but I'm unable to find the algorithm to get the inverse.

Comment: Take a $4\times 8$ matrix whose first 4 columns are your matrix, and the last 4 columns are the identity. Then row-reduce until you get the identity on the first 4 columns. The matrix you get on the last four columns is the inverse of your  matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, an inverse can be obtain through Gaussian elimination. Take an $n\times 2n$ matrix of the form $(A|I_n)$ ($I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix); row reduce until you get the identity in the first $n$ columns; the last $n$ columns are the inverse. Here:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1&1&1&1& 1& 0 & 0& 0\\
1& -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) &\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 0& 1 & 1 & -1 & -2 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align*}$$

So the inverse of your matrix is
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
1 & -1 & -2 & 2
\end{array}\right).$$

*Added.* The method can also be used if you don't know *whether* your matrix is invertible. Perform row reduction; if you get a row that has zeros on the first $n$ columns, then your original matrix was not invertible. Otherwise, you get the identity matrix on the left and obtain an inverse.

**Added 2.** It is also possible to figure out the inverse in an ad hoc manner because $A$ is fairly simple: interpret it as a linear transformation. The linear transformation maps $e_4$ to $e_1$, so the inverse must map $e_1$ to $e_4$, giving the first column.

$A$ maps $e_3$ to $e_1+e_2$, so the inverse must map $e_1+e_2$ to $e_3$; since it maps $e_1$ to $e_4$, the inverse maps $e_2 = (e_1+e_2)-e_1$ to $e_3-e_4$. That's the second column.

$A$ maps $e_2$ to $e_1-e_2+e_3$, so $A^{-1}$ maps $e_1-e_2+e_3$ to $e_2$; therefore, it maps $e_3 = (e_1-e_2+e_3) +(e_1+e_2) - 2e_1$ to $e_2 + e_3 -2e_4$. This gives the third column.

And finally, since $A$ maps $e_1$ to $e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4$, $A^{-1}$ maps $e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4$ to $e_1$. Hence it maps $e_4= (e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4) - (e_1-e_2+e_3)-2(e_1+e_2)+2e_1$ to $e_1-e_2-2e_3+2e_4$.

Of course, this amounts to just doing the row-reduction in an ad hoc manner...

Answer (score 3):

Another way.  Let your matrix be $A$.  Then $A = J B$ where $$J = \pmatrix{0&0&0&1\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr}, \ B = JA = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 1 & -1 & 1 & 0\cr 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr}$$ since multiplying by $J$ on the left flips the matrix vertically (interchanging first and fourth rows and second and third rows).

Now $B$ is a lower triangular matrix.  We can write it as $I + N$ where the nonzero entries of $N$ are all below the main diagonal.  Thus $N^4 = 0$ and 
$$ B^{-1} = I - N + N^2 - N^3 =\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr} - \pmatrix{ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \cr}
+ \pmatrix{ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \cr}
- \pmatrix{ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr}
= \pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr -2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \cr 2 & -2 & -1 & 1 \cr}
$$

We'll then have $$A^{-1} = B^{-1} J^{-1} = B^{-1} J = \pmatrix{ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \cr 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 \cr 1 & -1 & -2 & 2 \cr}
$$ where multiplying by $J$ on the right flips the matrix horizontally (interchanging first and fourth columns and second and third columns).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by inspection. Let $X$ be the inverse, and $\overline{x_i}$ the i-th row.
Then

$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
X
= I
$$

So, considering first the last row, we get

$$ (1 \;  \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}0) \left(\begin{array}{r} \overline{x_1} \\ \overline{x_2} \\ \overline{x_3} \\ \overline{x_4}  \end{array}\right) = \overline{x_1} = (0 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}1) $$

Then, from row 3 we get

$$(1 \;  \phantom{-}1 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}0) \left(\begin{array}{r} \overline{x_1} \\ \overline{x_2} \\ \overline{x_3} \\ \overline{x_4} \end{array}\right) 
= \overline{x_1} + \overline{x_2} =  (0 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}1 \; \phantom{-}0)  \Rightarrow \overline{x_2} = (0 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}1 \; -1)
$$

and

$$(1 \;  -1 \; \phantom{-}1 \; \phantom{-}0) \left(\begin{array}{r} \overline{x_1} \\ \overline{x_2} \\ \overline{x_3} \\ \overline{x_4} \end{array}\right) 
= \overline{x_1} - \overline{x_2} + \overline{x_3} =  (0 \; \phantom{-}1 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}0)  \Rightarrow \overline{x_3} = (0 \; \phantom{-}1 \; \phantom{-}1 \; -2)
$$

$$(1 \;  \phantom{-}1 \; \phantom{-}1 \; \phantom{-}1) \left(\begin{array}{r} \overline{x_1} \\ \overline{x_2} \\ \overline{x_3} \\ \overline{x_4}  \end{array}\right) 
= \overline{x_1} + \overline{x_2} + \overline{x_3} + \overline{x_4} =  (1 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}0 \; \phantom{-}0)  \Rightarrow \overline{x_4} = (1 \; -1 \; -2 \; \phantom{-}2)
$$